# Is there a shortcut to 'Close Project' in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

If it is a frequent ritual, it becomes an ordeal to right click on the project/s and select close project everytime.

Comment: +1 for calling it a ritual :D

Comment: :) I'm glad that it fetched me a point!

Comment: You're either delivering often (yes!) or switching contexts very often (boo!)

Comment: @pall. +1 for asking this question. I have mapped **Alt + C** for closing project.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is nothing defined by default but you can define your own binding from

`Window > Preferences > General > Keys` 
[image]

Comment: ENTER key already opens a project in Package workspace tab but did not toggle. Binding ENTER to CloseProject action made it a toggle. Exactly what users are expecting to experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind own key for 'Close Project' in menu([Window] - [Preferences] - [Keys]).

Comment: Thank you too. I accepted the other answer as it was posted earlier.